# How to render a PDF browsing component in Chrome when using streamlit?

Tags: python, google-chrome, streamlit

Here are the code using streamlit to render a PDF in browser:

```
base64_pdf = base64.b64encode(uploaded.read()).decode("utf-8")
if method == "Embed":
    pdf_display = (
        f'<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,{base64_pdf}" '
        'width="800" height="1000" type="application/pdf"></embed>'
    )
elif method == "Iframe":
    pdf_display = (
        f'<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{base64_pdf}" '
        'width="800" height="1000" type="application/pdf"></iframe>'
    )
elif method == "object":
    pdf_display = (
        f'<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,{base64_pdf}" '
        'width="800" height="1000" type="application/pdf"></object>'
    )
```

I have done some experiments. It failed when using Chrome and Edge with the PDF file size larger than 1MB.

Firefox can support this PDF browsing component but Firefox is not commonly used. Therefore, I want to find a way to display it in Chrome.

Comment: Sadly there are no ways to do this at the moment. It's one of the biggest drawback of streamlit. You can try to split your PDF in smaller PDFs or convert the PDF in images and display images in a carrousel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of hard work, I suddenly found a way. Directly pass base64 strings as content of PDF is very redundant.

Using url like `"src=http://localhost:8900/filename.pdf"` is a much more relaxed way. Therefore, we can choose directly store the pdf file uploaded by user:

```
uploaded_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader(
label="Upload PDF files", type=["pdf"], accept_multiple_files=False
)

if not uploaded_file:
   st.session_state.clear()
   st.info("请在左侧上传您的PDF文件")
   st.stop()

@st.cache_resource(ttl="1h")
def configure_PDF(file):
   with open(os.path.join("/your_path/user_upload_pdfs", file.name), "wb") as f:
   f.write(uploaded_file.getvalue())
```

The next step is to start up a HTTP server locally by:

```
python -m http.server 8900
```

at /your_path/user_upload_pdfs.

Then files can be accessed by `'http://localhost:8900/filename.pdf'`

Finally, with any type of component like "embed", "iframe" or "object" to view a PDF in Browser, coding like:

```
<embed src="http://localhost:8900/{file.name}" type="application/pdf" width="1000px" height="1100px" />
```

In a production environment considering privacy, you can do more development on the HTTP server that temporarily stores PDF files.